# IE issue min margin-top Legends within a Fieldset

Tags: css, internet-explorer, legend, fieldset

Got some IE issue with fieldsets, as you can see in the image is that IE even IE9 doesn't get the `margin-top: -26px;` Someone how knows the fix?

```
fieldset{
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top-color: #AAA;
  border-left-color: #AAA;
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 35px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

legend {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: -11px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}
```

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhb2.png

edit: Google chrome has the same issue

Comment: Please people stop using negative margins :| From the spec: `Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits.` so I would always suggest to not use it. It also doesn't sound logic to have a negative margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fieldsets and legends are notoriously hard to style the same way across different browsers.  You should really style to their limitations and not style to what you want.  With that said... if you're still stubborn and want to ***do the wrong thing*** you should put an element within the `legend` that you style.  Something like this ([see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drZWu/1/)) will work for Chrome and IE (Note: it will **not** look right for Firefox).

```
fieldset{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top-color: #AAA;
    border-left-color: #AAA;
    background: #EEE;
    margin: 35px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
legend {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
legend span {
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left: -11px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

A couple things to note...

1. By positioning the legend absolute, you trick the browser into styling the border on the entire top of the fieldset. If this wasn't done there would be a little gap where the fieldset is.
2. You're makign a ton of assumptions about how the browser will style this that may or may not be right.

Comment: I think the trick here is that the `fieldset` rule includes `position:relative` - IE needs that explicit rule on the parent container of the legend to have the negative margins or negative position work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the 'span did the trick. But I indeed changed the build of my systeem. I wasnt thinking about the purpose of a fieldset. so I created into divs.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
.fieldset{display: block;
```

works for me

Comment: In your code you're styling elements with `.fieldset` class not the `fieldset` element ... Also you forgot the closing brackets `}`